# php-cs-fixer wrong formatting

Tags: php, php-8.2, php-cs-fixer

Environment:
Mx Linux 23.1 (Debian 12)
PHP 8.2.7
Vscodium 1.85.2 
php-cs-fixer-v3.phar (https://cs.symfony.com/) 
friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer: "^3.42"

In this case, I don't think the editor has any impact on this behavior, but still I am adding my version.
I am running into a strange behavior which I cannot explain after investigation.
I am using PHP-CS-FIXER to format my PHP code and the indentation is wrong.

Here is my .php-cs-fixer.php file:

```
<?php

return (new PhpCsFixer\Config())
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR12' => true,
        'array_indentation' => true,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
        'combine_consecutive_unsets' => true,
        'class_attributes_separation' => ['elements' => ['method' => 'one',]],
        'multiline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => false,
        'single_quote' => true,

        'binary_operator_spaces' => [
            'operators' => [
                // '=>' => 'align',
                // '=' => 'align'
            ]
        ],
        // 'blank_line_after_opening_tag' => true,
        // 'blank_line_before_statement' => true,
        'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true,
        ],
        // 'cast_spaces' => true,
        // 'class_definition' => array('singleLine' => true),
        'concat_space' => ['spacing' => 'one'],
        'declare_equal_normalize' => true,
        'function_typehint_space' => true,
        'single_line_comment_style' => ['comment_types' => ['hash']],
        'include' => true,
        'lowercase_cast' => true,
        // 'native_function_casing' => true,
        // 'new_with_braces' => true,
        // 'no_blank_lines_after_class_opening' => true,
        // 'no_blank_lines_after_phpdoc' => true,
        // 'no_blank_lines_before_namespace' => true,
        // 'no_empty_comment' => true,
        // 'no_empty_phpdoc' => true,
        // 'no_empty_statement' => true,
        'no_extra_blank_lines' => [
            'tokens' => [
                'curly_brace_block',
                'extra',
                // 'parenthesis_brace_block',
                // 'square_brace_block',
                'throw',
                'use',
            ]
        ],
        // 'no_leading_import_slash' => true,
        // 'no_leading_namespace_whitespace' => true,
        // 'no_mixed_echo_print' => array('use' => 'echo'),
        'no_multiline_whitespace_around_double_arrow' => true,
        // 'no_short_bool_cast' => true,
        // 'no_singleline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => true,
        'no_spaces_around_offset' => true,
        // 'no_trailing_comma_in_list_call' => true,
        // 'no_trailing_comma_in_singleline_array' => true,
        // 'no_unneeded_control_parentheses' => true,
        // 'no_unused_imports' => true,
        'no_whitespace_before_comma_in_array' => true,
        'no_whitespace_in_blank_line' => true,
        // 'normalize_index_brace' => true,
        'object_operator_without_whitespace' => true,
        // 'php_unit_fqcn_annotation' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_align' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_annotation_without_dot' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_indent' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_inline_tag' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_access' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_alias_tag' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_empty_return' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_package' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_useless_inheritdoc' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_return_self_reference' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_scalar' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_separation' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_single_line_var_spacing' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_summary' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_to_comment' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_trim' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_types' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_var_without_name' => true,
        // 'increment_style' => true,
        // 'return_type_declaration' => true,
        // 'self_accessor' => true,
        // 'short_scalar_cast' => true,
        // 'single_blank_line_before_namespace' => true,
        // 'single_class_element_per_statement' => true,
        // 'space_after_semicolon' => true,
        // 'standardize_not_equals' => true,
        'ternary_operator_spaces' => true,
        // 'trailing_comma_in_multiline' => ['elements' => ['arrays']],
        'trim_array_spaces' => true,
        'unary_operator_spaces' => true,
        'whitespace_after_comma_in_array' => true,
        'space_after_semicolon' => true,
        // 'single_blank_line_at_eof' => false
    ])
    // ->setIndent("\t")
    ->setLineEnding("\n")
;
```

When I run php-cs-fixer I get wrong indentation format on some lines. Starting with $query =..

```
            <?php
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = {$id}");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $res_uname = $result['Username'];
    $res_email = $result['Email'];
    $res_age = $result['Age'];
    $res_id = $result['Id'];
}
echo <<<IDF
            <a href="edit.php?Id={$res_id}">Change profile</a>
            IDF;

?>
```

Complete formatted code below:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
require 'php/config.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <p><a href="home.php" class="logo-link">Logo</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-links">
            <?php
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = {$id}");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $res_uname = $result['Username'];
    $res_email = $result['Email'];
    $res_age = $result['Age'];
    $res_id = $result['Id'];
}
echo <<<IDF
            <a href="edit.php?Id={$res_id}">Change profile</a>
            IDF;

?>    
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

However if I remove the top part from the complete code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
require 'php/config.php';

?>
```

Php-cs-fixer will work correctly and the format will be like expected. See below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <p><a href="home.php" class="logo-link">Logo</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-links">
            <?php
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = {$id}");
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $res_uname = $result['Username'];
                $res_email = $result['Email'];
                $res_age = $result['Age'];
                $res_id = $result['Id'];
            }
            echo <<<IDF
            <a href="edit.php?Id={$res_id}">Change profile</a>
            IDF;

            ?>
       </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-cs-fixer shows you the formatting this way because you have mixed-content. First you have the php code, then you have the html. Inside the html structure, you add multi-line php code that breaks the html logic. A clear structure will be when you have php logic first, and then embed the php code through single-line constructs. Like this:

```
<?php
require 'php/config.php';

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
} else {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = {$id}");

    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $res_uname = $result['Username'];
        $res_email = $result['Email'];
        $res_age = $result['Age'];
        $res_id = $result['Id'];
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="logo">
                <p><a href="home.php" class="logo-link">Logo</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-links">
                <a href="edit.php?Id=<?= $res_id; ?>">Change profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, separation / re-ordering between logic and html should be improved for sure.